# ClojureScript Figwheel - REPL fails to recover prompt after error

Tags: clojurescript, figwheel

I'm wondering how to get figwheel to recover after an error is thrown in the REPL. I'm starting figwheel from a cli tools set up (no lein).

```
=> clojure -m figwheel.main --build somebuild --repl
```

Once an error is thrown (this doesn't happen with every error tho) I lose the REPL prompt and have to ctrl-c kill and reboot figwheel (which is terrible for productivity).

Here is an example.

```
cljs.user=> (swap! throw an unrecoverable error)
```

This shows some obvious error messages (non of those vars bind to anything), returns a `#object[Error: ...]`, but then the prompt is gone and I can't recover the REPL.

I've tried refreshing the browser tab, hot reloading files, nothing recovers the prompt. Is there a particular set up for figwheel to insure this doesn't happen?

Fighweel version below.

```
{:deps {com.bhauman/figwheel-main {:mvn/version "0.2.3"}
        com.bhauman/rebel-readline-cljs {:mvn/version "0.1.4"}}}
```

Comment: You might need to install rlwrap (https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap) utility for your Terminal. Please let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue.

See issue https://github.com/bhauman/figwheel-main/issues/161